# ReSharper complains about the switch statement it generated -- "Cannot resolve symbol ..."

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, resharper

I am using ReSharper, and I ran into two scenarios when generating a switch statement:

```
public void DoWork(MyEnum value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        // ...

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
    }
}

public void DoWork()
{
    var value = GetEnumValue();

    switch(value)
    {
        // ...

        default:
            // Cannot resolve symbol 'value'
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
    }
}
```

---

It seems that if I pass in the enumeration value as a parameter, ReSharper doesn't complain about the code it generates. It recognizes that `value` is appropriately used in the exception message.

But, if I acquire the value as a local variable some other way within the method, ReSharper seems to complain about the code it generates, claiming that *"Cannot resolve symbol 'value'"*. This sort of makes sense, because the `value` is a local variable, so a consumer capturing the exception message has no idea what `value` really is.

So, why does this happen?

Comment: Why not use a custom exception? If you don't have any argument, throwing an ArgumentOutOfRange is pretty weird and counterintuitive.

Comment: Custom exceptions are often not implemented correctly. For example, they often are not serialized correctly or contain fields of non-serializable types, which cause problems when your exception tries to cross an AppDomain boundary. If you *do* implement your own exception, I'd advise following all of the details on MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsw6yh2a(v=vs.110).aspx) the `paramName` should be the value of a parameter:

> The name of the parameter that causes this exception.

So you should be using the name of a parameter there, not a local. Even though Resharper generated it, it has no way of making this change, not without making breaking changes, like changing the exception type.

Perhaps a better exception in this case would be an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you're using the wrong type of `Exception`. In the second example `value` isn't an argument, so it is semantically wrong to throw a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. I've create a custom `Exception` to use in such cases, you're welcome to use it for your purposes as well:

```
public class UnexpectedEnumException : Exception
{
    public UnexpectedEnumException(Type enumType, object unexpectedValue)
        : base(string.Concat("Unexpected ", enumType.Name, ": ", unexpectedValue))
    {
    }

    public static UnexpectedEnumException Create<TEnum>(TEnum unexpectedValue) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable, IComparable
    {
        return new UnexpectedEnumException(typeof (TEnum), unexpectedValue);
    }
}
```